# Pasting from MSWord how can I remove <p> tags inside of <ol>/<ul> tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm removing junk tags from html pasted from MSWord into my NicEdit RTE.

```
<OL>
<LI>Hello</LI>
<P dir=ltr align=left>
<LI>Two</LI>
<P></P>
<P dir=ltr align=left>
<LI>Three</LI>
<P></P>
<P dir=ltr align=left>
<LI></LI>
<P></P></OL>
```

I'm already stripping a whole bunch of tags that our application doesn't use. However we do use `<p>` tags so I can't just strip out all the `<p>` tags that get pasted in.

I need a fast (not necessarily accurrate) means of stripping `<p>` tags inside of `<ol>` and `<ul>` tags.

I have `</?p\s?.*?>` to match a `p` tag but I don't know how to check if I'm inside `ol` or `ul`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'm worried that it will be too slow. Hmm, that has me thinking though maybe I'll try that and see how fast it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regex, use DOM manipulating:

```
var div = document.createElement("div"),
    p;

div.innerHTML = str;
p = div.querySelectorAll("ol p, ul p");

for (var i = 0, len = p.length; i < len; i++) {
    p[i].parentNode.removeChild(p[i]);
}

console.log(div.innerHTML);
```

Note that `querySelectorAll` is very useful in your problem, however it is supported only by modern browsers. See compatibility information at [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll#Browser_compatibility).

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bSdMW/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using HtmlTidy from http://tidy.sourceforge.net/? You may not need to write your own source code at all. In any case, using regexes to parse XML is fraught with danger.